# How to display a list of values in the jQuery plugin data tables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatable

I am having problems in the front end with the data tables JQuery plugin. I receive an array that contains arrays from the back end, i.e.,

```
# In console I receive
[Array(16), Array(16), Array(16), Array(16), Array(16), Array(16)]

#structure of the array
[[1021972, 'John B.','2017-08-04 01:34:18','2017-09-05 00:29:01', 'Transferred'],
 [1036722, 'John P.', '2017-09-01 00:34:18','2017-10-02 00:59:59','Researching'],
 [1015621, 'John D.','2017-01-01 00:00:18','2017-09-01 20:20:57', 'Closed'],
 [1045971, 'John C.', '2016-05-01 02:32:18','2017-09-05 12:29:01', 'Transferred'],
 [1445872, 'John A.', '2017-05-01 06:30:17','2017-05-02 08:49:11', 'Deferred']];
```

I use the following code for trying to display the results in the JQuery data tables plugin but without success, i.e.,

```
#HTML 
<table id="reservations" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Open Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Ticket Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

#JQuery plugin Data Tables
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reservations').DataTable();
});
```

I am concerned that I need a for loop to throw the content of each array in the data tables but I am not so sure how to do this. I also have the following [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d9myxfp/1/), so you can do your tests. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: use [**`data: reservations`**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d9myxfp/2/)

Comment: You haven't shown code where you are getting `array of arrays`. So I'll not be in position to answer your query

Comment: @davidkonrad, your solution worked.